# Wordpress category not counting media attachments

Tags: wordpress, count, attachment, categories, taxonomy

In Wordpress I am creating a gallery that will automatically display new images from a chosen category and its subcategories. I have set up the categories so that they will apply to media using:

```
register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'attachment' );
```

Now I need to make it so that categories will count the related attachments not just posts.
I found this link How to Override default update_count_callback for category with this code:

```
function change_category_arg() {
    global $wp_taxonomies;
    if ( ! taxonomy_exists('category') )
        return false;

    $new_arg = &$wp_taxonomies['category']->update_count_callback;
    $new_arg->update_count_callback = 'your_new_arg';

}
add_action( 'init', 'change_category_arg' );
```

But as of yet I have not figured it out (not sure if it doesn't work or if I'm just not understanding something, such as what would be 'your_new_arg').
I did find the update_count_callback function option when registering a new taxonomy but I don't want to make my own, I want to use it with the existing category taxonomy.

Any help with this is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hopefully this helps anyone that also had this problem. This is what I ended up putting in functions.php:

```
//Update Category count callback to include attachments
function change_category_arg() {
    global $wp_taxonomies;
    if ( ! taxonomy_exists('category') )
        return false;

    $wp_taxonomies['category']->update_count_callback = '_update_generic_term_count';
}
add_action( 'init', 'change_category_arg' );

//Add Categories taxonomy
function renaissance_add_categories_to_attachments() {
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'attachment' );
}
add_action( 'init' , 'renaissance_add_categories_to_attachments' );
```

Comment: I had a weird issue where image attachments would update the counter but pdf's would not. This fixed that issue.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. At first I thought it wasn't working because the counts weren't updating. But I had already created the taxonomy, and added a number of items to it before adding this function. Once I updated the count through the database, those counts were correct. And when I added more images to the taxonomy, the count within WordPress correctly changed. I wanted to mention that in case someone else used the function and thought that it did not work.

Comment: Looking for this solution for almost 2 hours :)). saved my day. thank you

Answer (score 1):

I've tested the answer from Victoria S and it is working.

But, if someone would like to avoid direct manipulation of WordPress globals, the below solution is based on native WordPress functions.

```
function my_add_categories_to_attachments() {
    $myTaxonomy = get_taxonomies(array('name' => 'category'), 'objects')['category'];
    $myTaxonomy->update_count_callback = '_update_generic_term_count';
    register_taxonomy ('category',
                       $myTaxonomy->object_type,
                       array_merge ((array) $myTaxonomy,
                                    array('capabilities' => (array) $myTaxonomy->cap)));

    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'attachment' );
}
add_action( 'init' , 'my_add_categories_to_attachments' );
```

The key here is that [`register_taxonomy`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) is used to recreate the `category` taxonomy identically, but changing the `update_count_callback` function. We use the taxonomy object from [`get_taxonomies`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_taxonomies) assigned to `$myTaxonomy`.

- The first argument is the Taxonomy slug we'd like to change: `'category'`
- The second argument is the array of object (post) types. We use it from the object returned by the `get_taxonomies`.
- The third argument (`$args`) is an array of the properties of the Taxonomy. We have to make sure to include everything properly from `$myTaxonomy`, to make sure the recreated `category` is identical to the original one, except for the changes we want, in this case modify the `update_count_callback` to use `_update_generic_term_count` instead of the default `_update_post_term_count`. The only issue is with the `capabilities` property, as it must be passed as `capabilities`, but is stored in the Taxonomy object as `cap`, therefore we need to extend the array of `$args` with the `cap` object cast as an array under the label of `capabilities`.

Please note, that for some reasons during my tests I saw the `labels` array of the recreated Taxonomy to include one additional item (`["archives"]=>"All Categories"`) compared to the original. This should not affect the system, as an additional label not referenced anywhere should not cause issues.

You can easily compare the Taxonomy before and after editing to make sure everything is in order by using `var_dump(get_taxonomies(array('name' => 'category'), 'objects')['category'])`. (Do not do that on production site unless you know what you are doing!)